# need blank cells added to table if data does not exist

Tags: php

This client has progress tracking for group leaders of their online course. The issue we are having is that this table references data from the db pertaining to the course, if this data does not exist then the logic never is able to create the blank cells that we need, leading to formatting issues. Tried a bunch of different ideas and I just can't get it to function properly. Please help.

Code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: User Course Record Leadership
*/
get_header(); 

 
$user_id=get_current_user_id();
$user=get_userdata($user_id); 
$useremail = $user->user_email;  
$userrole=$user->roles;
$usersemail=array(); 
global $wpdb; 
?>


  <div id="et-main-area">

<div id="main-content">


      
        <article id="post-262" class="post-262 page type-page status-publish hentry">

        
          <div class="entry-content">
            <?php 
while(have_posts()): the_post(); 
     the_content(); 
     endwhile;
            ?>

             <div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 et_section_regular">
        
        
        
        
          <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_0 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
        
        
        <div class="et_pb_text et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_text_0">
        
        
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
<?php  
  
if(is_user_logged_in()){ 
if($userrole[0]=='group_leader'){
$sql_str = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT usermeta.meta_value as group_ids FROM  wpb0_usermeta  as usermeta INNER JOIN  wpb0_posts  as posts ON posts.ID=usermeta.meta_value WHERE  user_id = %d  AND meta_key LIKE %s AND (posts.post_status = 'publish' OR posts.post_status = 'draft')", $user_id, 'learndash_group_leaders_%');
            $group_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql_str);

       //print_r($group_ids);   die;  
     foreach($group_ids as $ids){
           $key='learndash_group_users_'.intval($ids); 

        $getall_users  = $wpdb->get_results("select wpb0_users.ID,wpb0_users.user_email from wpb0_users inner join wpb0_usermeta on wpb0_users.ID =wpb0_usermeta.user_id  where wpb0_usermeta.meta_key='$key'"); 
        foreach($getall_users as $users){
         // echo $users->user_email.$ids;
         $usersemail['users'][] =array('user_id' =>$users->ID,'group_id'=>$ids,'user_email' => $users->user_email);    
        

       } 

            
     }
     $lession_complete= false; 
     echo "<table id='users_progress_leadership' class='display'>
            <thead>
               <tr>
               <tr>
               <th>  </th>
               <th> </th>
               <th> </th>
               <th> </th>
               <th> </th>
               <th> Modules </th>
               </tr>
                 <th>Employee Name</th>
                 <th>Color Self-Assessment</th>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <th>2</th>
                 <th>3</th>
                 <th>4</th>
                 <th>5</th>
                 <th>6</th>
                 <th>7</th>
                 <th>8</th>
                 <th>Course Completed</th>
                 <th>Results</th>
               </tr>
            </thead><tbody>";  
               
            foreach($usersemail['users'] as $userdata){
         
                   $dtd=  get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'] ,'_sfwd-course_progress',true);
                   
                ?>
                <tr><td><?php echo get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'],'first_name',true).' '.get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'],'last_name',true);  ?></td> 
            <?php   
                  
                
                $needle_keys=['21032', '20999','21001', '21004', '21007', '21009', '21013', '21015', '21018'];

foreach($dtd as $dt){

    $lessons_keys = array_keys($dt['lessons']);

            
                
    foreach($lessons_keys as $key){
        if(in_array($key, $needle_keys)){
            if($dt['lessons'][$key]){
                $lession_complete= true; 
                echo "<td>&#10003; </td>"; 
            } else  {
                echo "<td>  </td>"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
    


                        
                    
                
                

                   ?>
                  <td> <?php 
                     if($dt['completed']>='9'){
                     
                       echo "Complete "; 
                     } 
                   ?></td>
                       <td class="user-results">
                       <a href="https://hrhazmat.com/user-progress-report-single-page?group_id=<?php echo $ids;  ?>&user_id=<?php  echo $userdata['user_id'];  ?>"> View Results</a></td>
                  <?php
                  
         
              echo "</tr>"; 
           } 
             echo " </tbody></table >";
             echo "<style>
                 table.display th{
                 text-align:left; 
                 } 
                 
                 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
    color: #333 !important;
    /* border: 1px solid #979797; */
    background-color: #005574 !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #005574 50%, #d0b232 100%) !important;
    color: white !important;
    margin-bottom:12px !important; 
    } 
             </style>"; 
          
          
    }
    
}   

 
/*     .w3-table,.w3-table-all{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-bordered tr,.w3-table-all tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-hoverable tbody tr:hover,.w3-ul.w3-hoverable li:hover{background-color:#ccc}.w3-centered tr th,.w3-centered tr td{text-align:center}
.w3-table td,.w3-table th,.w3-table-all td,.w3-table-all th{padding:8px 8px;display:table-cell;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border:1px solid #0000002e; }
.w3-table th:first-child,.w3-table td:first-child,.w3-table-all th:first-child,.w3-table-all td:first-child{padding-left:16px}*/
?>
</div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
</article> 
</div>
</div>
<?php 
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by blank cells. How do you know if data is missing and blank cells need to be created? Is it that there are users missing form the group of lessons missing from those users in the group?

Comment: If it's that there are lessons missing - how do you know? Do you have a "master" list of all lessons for that group (possibly the `$needle_keys` array)?

Comment: So the way that these work is these needle keys are being pulled from a db created by the wordpress plugin that the courses come from. The issue is if a user has not started the course, this data does not exist so the logic from this section: foreach($lessons_keys as $key){
        if(in_array($key, $needle_keys)){
            if($dt['lessons'][$key]){
                $lession_complete= true; 
                echo "<td>&#10003; </td>"; 
            } else  {
                echo "<td>  </td>"; 
            }
        }
    }
} Never happens

Comment: And my apologies, what I mean by blank cells is you'll notice in the above comment the else statement echoes "<td> </td> This is the part that does not happen if there is no data to pull from.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague so there may be some assumptions here.

The main change that I think you need is to loop over your "master" lesson list instead of each user's lesson data (since it might not exist on that user).

I've improved the formatting and added comments to explain some of the changes.

```php
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    if ($userrole[0] == 'group_leader') {
        $sql_str = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT usermeta.meta_value as group_ids FROM  wpb0_usermeta  as usermeta INNER JOIN  wpb0_posts  as posts ON posts.ID=usermeta.meta_value WHERE  user_id = %d  AND meta_key LIKE %s AND (posts.post_status = 'publish' OR posts.post_status = 'draft')", $user_id, 'learndash_group_leaders_%');
        $group_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql_str);

        //print_r($group_ids);   die;  
        foreach ($group_ids as $ids) {
            $key = 'learndash_group_users_' . intval($ids);

            $getall_users  = $wpdb->get_results("select wpb0_users.ID,wpb0_users.user_email from wpb0_users inner join wpb0_usermeta on wpb0_users.ID =wpb0_usermeta.user_id  where wpb0_usermeta.meta_key='$key'");
            foreach ($getall_users as $users) {
                // echo $users->user_email.$ids;
                $usersemail['users'][] = array('user_id' => $users->ID, 'group_id' => $ids, 'user_email' => $users->user_email);
            }
        }

        ?>
        <table id='users_progress_leadership' class='display'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> Modules </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Color Self-Assessment</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>Course Completed</th>
                    <th>Results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($usersemail['users'] as $userdata) {
                    // rename variable for clarity
                    $user_courses = get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'], '_sfwd-course_progress', true);
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'], 'first_name', true) . ' ' . get_user_meta($userdata['user_id'], 'last_name', true);  ?></td>
                        <?php
                        // store $num_complete within the user loop
                        $num_complete = 0;
                        
                        // this is the "master" lesson id list
                        $master_lesson_ids = ['21032', '20999', '21001', '21004', '21007', '21009', '21013', '21015', '21018'];
                        
                        // create a "map" of this user's lesson ids
                        // we will only map those that exist in the "master" less list
                        $user_lesson_map = [];
                        foreach ($user_courses as $course) {
                            $user_lessons = $course["lessons"];
                            foreach($user_lessons as $lesson_id => $user_lesson){
                                if(!in_array($lesson_id, $master_lesson_ids)){
                                    // not in master list - go next
                                    continue;
                                }
                                
                                // the value store here doesn't matter
                                // as long as it's truthy
                                // we will just be using the "key"
                                $user_lesson_map[$lesson_id] = 1;
                            }
                        }


                        // instead of looping over the users lessons
                        // let's loop over the "master" lesson_ids
                        foreach ($master_lesson_ids as $lesson_id) {
                            if (!isset($user_lesson_map[$lesson_id])) {
                                // user has DOES NOT have data for this lesson
                                echo "<td>  </td>";
                                continue;
                            }

                            // user HAS data for this less
                            // assuming complete
                            echo "<td>&#10003; </td>";
                            $num_complete++;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            // check if $num_complete is the same length as
                            // the "master" lesson list
                            if ($num_complete === count($lesson_ids)) {
                                echo "Complete ";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="user-results">
                            <a href="https://hrhazmat.com/user-progress-report-single-page?group_id=<?php echo $ids;  ?>&user_id=<?php echo $userdata['user_id'];  ?>"> View Results</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <style>
            table.display th {
                text-align: left;
            }

            .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
            .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
                color: #333 !important;
                /* border: 1px solid #979797; */
                background-color: #005574 !important;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #005574 50%, #d0b232 100%) !important;
                color: white !important;
                margin-bottom: 12px !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: I've made an edit just now to resolve this - it actually brought up another issue with how that initial version was rendering the `<td>` elements. Now we create a "map" for each user based on all their courses/lessons - then we can use that map to determine whether it was complete or not.